# I want to show the user only 3 columns in UI, But want to Export all table data to excel, So how can I hide the column based on the header text?

Tags: javascript, datatables

This is My Table; I want to show only first 3 columns to User but I want to export all data to Excel. First how can I hide the columns based on the header text ?

```html
<table id="ibms" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>    
    <tr>                      
      <th>IBMS Code</th>
      <th>Location Description</th>
      <th>FMS Location Code</th>
      <th>FMS Location Description</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Zone</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>IB-0078</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>542</td>
      <td>Description here</td>
      <td>Industry</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Arizona</td>
      <td>five</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IB-552</td>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>576</td>
      <td>Description here</td>
      <td>Textile</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Texas</td>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS code:

```js
var hidecolumns = $("#ibms").DataTable();

function locationhie(hidecolumns){       
  var u = $("th:contains(FMS Location Description)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(u).visible( false );
}

function locationhieSite(hidecolumns){       
  var a = $("th:contains(Site)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(a).visible( false );
}

function locationhielevel(hidecolumns){       
  var b = $("th:contains(Level)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(b).visible( false );
}

function locationhieArea(hidecolumns){       
  var c = $("th:contains(Area)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(c).visible( false );
}

function locationhieZone(hidecolumns){       
  var d = $("th:contains(Zone)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(d).visible( false );
}

function locationhieUnit(hidecolumns){       
  var e = $("th:contains(Unit)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(e).visible( false );
}

function locationhieLocation(hidecolumns){       
  var f = $("th:contains(Location)").index();
  hidecolumns.column(f).visible( false );
}
```

Can Anyone help me how to achieve this ? Is there any alternative solutions available to do this in a single function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class selector to hide some columns, no JS needed:

```css
.locations td:nth-child(n+4),
.locations th:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table id="ibms" class="table table-bordered locations">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>IBMS Code</th>
      <th>Location Description</th>
      <th>FMS Location Code</th>
      <th>FMS Location Description</th>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Area</th>
      <th>Zone</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>IB-0078</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>542</td>
      <td>Description here</td>
      <td>Industry</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Arizona</td>
      <td>five</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IB-552</td>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>576</td>
      <td>Description here</td>
      <td>Textile</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Texas</td>
      <td>one</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>USA</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`.locations td:nth-child(n+4)` selects any `td` element within an element of `.locations` class starting from the index of 4. Indices are calculated from the first occurence of `td` in its parent, and the first index is 1.

Comment: its working fine. But what if I want to hide some columns in between , For example, how I have to modify the above code to hide columns  FMS Location Code,Level and Unit ?

Comment: Just read the MDN article about `nth-child` linked in my answer, you can select almost any combination with that selector. When you need to change the column visibility, create classes like `locations` with a suitable `nth-child` selector, and then change the class of `table` with JS.